# use parent schema value as default value of child schema in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const ParentSchema = new Schema({
    key1: {type: String, required: true},
    key2: {type: String, required: true},
    child: {type: [ChildSchema], default: ChildSchema}
})

const ChildSchema = new Schema({
    key3: {type: String, default: '**Value of Key1**'},
    key4: {type: String}
})
```

Here I have two schemas one is a parent schema and another one is child schema, I want to set Key1 value as a default value of Key3. Key1 value is a dynamic value that will be entered by the user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Mongoose population.

```
const ParentSchema = new Schema({
    key1: {type: String, required: true},
    key2: {type: String, required: true}
})

const ChildSchema = new Schema({
    key3: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ParentSchema' }
    key4: {type: String}
})
```

Then, you can populate ChildSchema like this:

```
ChildSchema.
  findById(someId).
  populate('key3', 'key1').
  exec(errorHandlingCb);
```

For detail implementation see [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Comment: Is there any other way we can do it because the mongoose population method will create conflicts in my further flow.